# Safari issue with column wrap

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

HTML:

```
<div class = "main-container">
  <div class = "item-1">
    <div class = "simple_list1">
      <div class = "header_left">
        <div class = "it-1">Predictive analysis</div>
        <div class = "it-2">Cool idea</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "simple_list2">Current Analysis</div>
  </div>
  <div class = "item-2">Java</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main-container{
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row wrap;
  width:350px;
  height:46px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
.main-container > .item-1{
  display:flex;
  width:auto;
  flex-flow:column wrap;
  border:1px solid blue;

}

.main-container > .item-2{
  display:flex;
  width:auto;
  margin-left:auto!important;
  border:1px solid green;
}
.header_left{
  display:flex;
  width:auto;
  flex-flow:row wrap;
  border:2px solid red;
}
```

Open this page in safari and in chrome.In chrome the flex children are tightly wrapped(column wrap)
but in safari there is a extra space in safari.i am not sure why this extra space is there please clarify and provide the fix for it.
also i am not sure which behaviour is correct,the safari one or the chrome one

Answer (score 0):

Use vendor prefixes

```
.main-container > .item-2{
  display:flex;
  display:-webkit-flex;
  width:auto;
  margin-left:auto!important;
  border:1px solid green;
}
.header_left{
  display:-webkit-flex;
  width:auto;
  -webkit-flex-flow:row wrap;
  border:2px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
display: -webkit-flex;                        /* Safari */
         -webkit-flex-flow: row-reverse wrap; /* Safari 6.1+ */
```